# user upload limit set to 10 videos a day on youtube api?

Tags: youtube-api

So I'm building an app that is supposed to allow a user to upload a lot of videos from their google drive to their youtube. It works beyond the fact that the youtube api has a hard video limit of 10 videos per day per user. I can find nowhere in the documentation where it says there is a 10 video limit nor anywhere I can request a higher user limit. My quota is already increased to allow plenty of videos per day, around 100 app wide, but this userUploadLimit error still happens as soon as any one user uploads 10 videos in a 24hr period.

I've tried looking through the documentation for any mention of this issue, only place I can find it mentioned was in the section of the docs that talks about errors. Anyone face this issue before and is there a work around or do I just ask them for a user upload increase in the same spot I asked for a quota increase? I see in the past people were able to upload 50 videos at a time but right now I can only upload 10.